# List indexes on a recursive program?

Tags: prolog

I've been searching for something that might help me with my problem all over the internet but I haven't been able to make any progress. I'm new to logic programming and English is not my first language so apologize for any mistake.

Basically I want to implement this prolog program: `discord/3` which has arguments L1, L2 lists and P where P are the indexes of the lists where `L1[P] != L2[P]` (in Java). In case of different lengths, the not paired indexes just fail. Mode is `(+,+,-) nondet`.

I got down the basic case but I can't seem to wrap my head around on how to define P in the recursive call.

```
discord(_X,[],_Y) :-
    fail.
discord([H1|T1],[H1|T2],Y) :-
    ???
    discord(T1,T2,Z).
discord([_|T1],[_|T2],Y) :-
    ???
    discord(T1,T2,Z).
```

The two clauses above are what I came up to but I have no idea on how to represent Y - and Z - so that the function actually remembers the length of the original list. I've been thinking about using `nth/3` with eventually an `assert` but I'm not sure where to place them in the program.

I'm sure there has to be an easier solution although. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add an example query to your question? Like this (just guessing): `?- discord([a,b,c],[x,b,y], [1,3]).` should be true?

Comment: Exactly! The mode I meant to use was `(+,+,-)` so a sample query could be something like `?- discord([a,b,c], [d,e,c], X)` which should give answers `X=1; X=2` or `?- discord([1,2,3], [1,2,3], X)` which should answer `false`

Comment: It would be enough to write `dif(X, Y), nth1(P, L1, X), nth1(P, L2, Y)`

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean? I tried this implementation but it doesn't work, If I have a true answer it always answers `P=1`- because the recursion doesn't remember the length of the original list!

`discord(_X,[],_Y) :- fail.`
`discord([],_X,_Y) :- fail.`
`discord([X|T1],[Y|T2],P) :- dif(X,Y), nth1(P, [X|T1], X), nth1(P,  [Y|T2], Y), discord(T1,T2,P).`

Comment: No need for recursive predicate at all, this code snippet is the full definition of your `discord/3`. You can also write a recursive predicate for this, but maybe unnecessary.

Comment: The following query on the top level: `?- L1 = [a,b,c,d], L2 = [x,b,y,d], dif(X, Y), nth1(P, L1, X), nth1(P, L2, Y).` tells me that `P = 1` and `P = 3`.

Comment: You're totally right! I was so stung on the recursive call which wasnt necessary. This worked thanks!

Comment: See the answer too.

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this in two ways. First, the more declarative way would be to enumerate the indexed elements of both lists with `nth1/3` and use `dif/2` to ensure that the two elements are different:

```
?- L1 = [a,b,c,d],
   L2 = [x,b,y,d],
   dif(X, Y),
   nth1(P, L1, X),
   nth1(P, L2, Y).
X = a, Y = x, P = 1 ;
X = c, Y = y, P = 3 ;
false.
```

You could also attempt to go through both list at the same time and keep a counter:

```
discord(L1, L2, P) :-
    discord(L1, L2, 1, P).

discord([X|_], [Y|_], P, P) :-
    dif(X, Y).
discord([_|Xs], [_|Ys], N, P) :-
    succ(N, N1),
    discord(Xs, Ys, N1, P).
```

Then, from the top level:

```
?- discord([a,b,c,d], [a,x,c,y], Ps).
Ps = 2 ;
Ps = 4 ;
false.
```